# SSRS stacked column chart legend is Wrong after adding lookset() inside the Action

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have Stacked column chart which is working fine. now i added the drill down added parameter Student id i have to pass this id to the next report . this is my chart below [image: SSRS stacked column chart legend is Wrong after adding lookset inside the Action]
you can see that after adding the lookupSet() , legend is wrong 
This is My code 
LookupSet( Fields!Year.Value , Fields!Year.Value,Fields!StudentId.Value,"DataSet1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Lookup Data Set we can achieve this